# How to copy and paste a formula changing only the cell references made on this sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, copy-paste

How can I copy and paste a formula changing only the cell references made on the active sheet and leave references to ranges on another sheet as is?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what you've tried so far? Screenshots/formula would be helpful.

Here is my attempt to answer your question based on the available information:

```
=A2+'Copy of Sheet1'!$D$2
```

Add `$` to reference what you want to keep. `$` will retain either column, row, or both.